# Not able to output the Public IP from EKS module worker node in Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks

I'm trying to output the public IP assigned to the worker node in EKS module in Terraform.

I'm not using any loadbalancer and the public IP is assigned correctly to the worker node.

However, the `terraform show --json` command is not showing this Public IP so I'm not sure how to output it in terraform as the module has no any specific output for this purpose.

EKS module:

```bash
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "~> 19.0"

  cluster_name    = "eks-${var.sandbox_id}"
  cluster_version = "1.24"

  cluster_addons = {
    coredns = {
      most_recent = true
    }
    kube-proxy = {
      most_recent = true
    }
    vpc-cni = {
      most_recent = true
    }
  }

  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true
  cluster_endpoint_public_access  = true

  vpc_id     = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnet_ids = module.vpc.public_subnets
  
  kms_key_administrators = local.kms_key_vars
  enable_irsa = true
  create_kms_key = true
  create_cluster_security_group = false
  cluster_security_group_id = aws_security_group.my_sg.id

  eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
    disk_size = 100
  }

  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    general = {
      desired_size = 1
      min_size     = 1
      max_size     = 3

      labels = {
        env = "test"
      }

      instance_types = ["t3.small"]
      capacity_type  = "ON_DEMAND"
      network_interfaces = [{
        associate_public_ip_address = true
      }]
    }
  }

  create_aws_auth_configmap = false
  manage_aws_auth_configmap = true
  
  aws_auth_users = local.aws_auth_var

  tags = {
    env = "test"
  }
}
```